# Javascript conditional return statement (Shorthand if-else statement)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ternary-operator

While writing shorthand if-else in javascript,getting syntax error. Here is my code:

```
data && data.cod   ==  '404' && return;
```

Although works fine when I use normal if-else like below:

```
        if(data && data.cod   ==  '404') {return};
        var temp        =   data && data.main && data.main.temp;
       //Code here...
```

I know, it works fine if I use ternary operator like `return (data && data.cod   ==  '404')?'true':'false';` but I'm looking "return" on conditional basis otherwise continue further.

Comment: what's ternary here ??? `data && data.cod   ==  '404' && return;`

Comment: question is little bit unclear....

Comment: A `return` statement is a _statement_. It's not an expression and you can't use it as one.

Comment: My bad ! . Actually i have tried using ternary operator first then changes its implementation as needed..(Updated my ques). its not about ternary operator its about short hand syntax for return.

Comment: it is not possible but i like the idea so voting up :-). It will help us to further reduce the code.

Comment: Related: [Why can't we have return in the ternary operator?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35231609/1048572)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

What you're trying to do is a violation of syntax rules.

The `return` keyword can only be used at the beginning of a [*return statement*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-12.9)

In `data && data.cod == '404' && <something>`, the only thing you can place in `<something>` is an expression, not a statement. You can't put `return` there.

To return conditionally, use a proper `if` statement:

```
if(data && data.cod == '404') {
    return;
}
```

I would recommend against using shortcuts like you're trying to do as a "clever" way to execute code with side effects. The purpose of the conditional operator and boolean operators is to *produce a value*:

**Good:**

```
var value = condition ? valueWhenTrue : valueWhenFalse;
```

**Bad:**

```
condition ? doSomething() : doSomethingElse();
```

You shouldn't be doing this, even if the language allows you to do so. That's not what the conditional operator is intended for, and it's confusing for people trying to make sense of your code.

Use a proper `if` statement for that. That's what it's for:

```
if (condition) {
    doSomething();
} else {
    doSomethingElse();
}
```

You can put it on one line if you really want to:

```
if (condition) { doSomething(); } else { doSomethingElse(); }
```

Comment: Excellent answer! Stuff like this is one of the reasons Douglas Crockford wrote [JSLint](http://www.jslint.com/) and why it is so strict. He wanted to keep himself from trying to write "clever" code. Writing "clever" code often leads to introducing hard to debug bugs.

Answer (score 0):

Well then just write the return in the if

```
var result = (data && data.cod   ==  '404') 
if (result) {
  return result;
} else {
    //otherwise
}
```