# Why can't we have return in the ternary operator?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Say I've a simple `form` and I want to check whether `form` has changed or not. If its changed `submit` it else prevent form submission, so I used return and instead of using `if-else` statement I tried to use `ternary operation` but unfortunately I was hit with error **`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token return`** but I did not understand why this error? Is ternary operation only used to assign? Not sure on this part. Below is just a sample of what I was trying to do.

```js
var form_original_data = $("#frmProfile").serialize();

$("#frmProfile").on('submit', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $("#frmProfile").serialize() != form_original_data ? $("body").append('changed') : return;
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="frmProfile">
  <input type="text" value="name" />
  <input type="submit" value="Go" />
</form>
```

Comment: makes no sense... Use an if

Comment: @epascarello No I would go with `if` no probs, but is this invalid to perform?

Comment: Return what exactly? The ternary operator is generally used as `var x = toCheck ? true : false;`

Comment: return in the sense breaking out or say preventing default action i.e. submit... @adeneo..

Comment: Yes exactly, nothing is being returned and the `.on('submit')` is not being called as a function which returns a value that is stored ?

Comment: To prevent the submit, you'd have to do more than just return, you'd have to return `false`. This is just so easily done with `if ($("#frmProfile").serialize() != form_original_data) e.preventDefault()` that there's no need for a ternary

Answer (score 75, accepted):

The ternary operator evaluates to an expression and expressions can't contain a return statement (how would that behave if you were to assign the expression to a variable?). However, you could very well return the result of a ternary operator, i.e. `return condition? returnValue1 : returnValue2;`

On your specific point, I don't see why you would like to return. It looks like you're trying to do something only if a condition is fulfilled. A simple `if` statement would probably be more adequate there.

Comment: Agreed.. Only if is enough but as per definition **[here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)** for condition part which says `An expression that evaluates to true or false` My condition can either return `true` or `false` and based on that expression executes.. But why not return is my doubt.. Anyways you had elegant answer.. Accepting in T-5 minutes.. ;)

Comment: There's no problem about your condition but about what the MDN names `expr2` : it defines it is as an expression (something that can be evaluated to a value). The ternary operator isn't meant to execute an action or another but rather to yield a value or another. You can abuse it in much cases since most actions will return undefined or something more appropriate, but you can't do that with `return`.

Answer (score 19):

JavaScript (like many other languages) has **expressions** and **statements**. An expression must evaluate to something. A statement performs an action. Expressions can be used as statements, but the reverse is not true.

`return` is a [statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return). It does not evaluate to anything. You are using a [ternary expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) (a.k.a ternary operator), which has the syntax

```
test ? expression1 : expression2
```

and evaluates to `expression1` if the condition holds, and `expression2` otherwise. This implies that `expression1` and `expression2` must themselves evaluate to something, and cannot be statements.

---

Bottom line, you should use an `if`.

Answer (score 10):

There is a way to return a value with a ternary statement. I use this often when programming in Swift, as I believe that it cleans up code. In my opinion, this is much better than using an if statement. It saves a ton of code too.

Consider this:

```
var compare = function(a,b) {
    return (a == b ? true : false);
}
```

Now test it with:

```
console.log(compare(1,1));
console.log(compare(1,2));
```

Which evaluates to `true` and `false` respectively. While this is almost identical in Swift, I've verified that this Javascript code works.

Comment: Kind of `extension function` in `javascript`. Nice to know though, but the answer doesn't relate to my question..

Answer (score 8):

Because it is not syntactically correct. Here's the correct syntax for a ternary operator -

```
condition ? expr1 : expr2
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator

And `return` is not part of an expression. `return` is followed by an expression. (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return)

Answer (score 0):

yes, i also did a function like this:

```
const getContactByIdService = async (id) => {
  const data = await Contact.findById(id)
 !data ? return {status: 404, message: {"message": "Not found"}} : return {status: 200, message: data}
}
```

but ternary operator can't have return, but i can write like this:

```
 return !data ? {status: 404, message: {"message": "Not found"}} : {status: 200, message: data}
```

Answer (score -1):

this is function that has a return with a ternary

```
function tst(x, y = 1) {
    x == 0 ? x = 1 : y *= x;
  return x<=1? y:tst(x-1,y)
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please, consider adding a value on top of already provided answers, especially for a question that old for your answer to be well-received by peers. Do take a look at [how to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) if you haven't already. P.s. Please note that the question is about `return` keyword *inside* ternary (conditional) operator and why trying to do so results in `SyntaxError`