# how made a Return after conditional?

Tags: javascript, if-statement, return, conditional-statements, return-value

hey why we can not do this in JS ?

valur && return valur;

example

```
function inGUI(x, y){ // check if is in gui
    for (var i = DEBUG.children.length;i--;){
        var gui = DEBUG.children[i];
        var check = isInside.call(gui,x,y);
        check && return check; // not work

    };
};
```

why i need to make a IF condition

```
if(check){return check}
```

EDIT:
soleved thanks to everybody;
Fun way by @dave:

```
function inGUI(x, y){ // check if is in gui
    var is_inside = false;
    for (var i = this.children.length; !is_inside; i--){
        var gui = this.children[i];
        is_inside = isInside.call(gui,x,y);
    };
    return is_inside;
};
```

so cool

Comment: `not work` in what way? - never mind, yes, that's invalid syntax

Comment: Because that is how the language is... return's cannot be part of a conditional expression as return statements do not have a usable value to be used in a conditional way.

Comment: I ask why? i need understand, the syntax are logic

Comment: besides it being invalid, if i had to guess, it's not reading after the `return` ... in other words it's reading it as `check && return` .... why? probably because it's invalid syntax. you can't put a return statement there, so it is not behaving as expected.

Comment: When anything left of `&&` fails, the right side does not execute.

Comment: @PHPglue it's not even valid syntax, so it "shouldnt" run (unfortunately JS is JIT compiled).

See this other question which is similar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35231609/why-we-cannot-have-return-in-ternary-operator

Comment: short answer: because `return something` is a statement and doesn't evaluate to any value. `a && b` is an expression that does evaluate to some value, that can be used in statements.

Comment: If this is about shortening the code, you can do `function inGUI(x, y){ for(var c=DEBUG.children, i=c.length; i--;) if(isInside.call(c[i],x,y)) return true }`

Comment: thomas , no because it need return a obj with valur. ity for a debug tool in Node.js  https://youtu.be/3Dt-IXhE2fc 
it use document.addEventListener

Comment: ok, the used names don't give that away. You should consider renaming the functions to reflect what they return. At functions that are named `isSomething` or `inSomething` I'd expect to get a true or false. Just a suggestion

Comment: ok , thanks anyway for your participation, now i understand why. and also @dave give a good and fun other way .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the syntax of javascript does not allow it.

> expr1 && expr2
>
> && returns expr1 if it can be converted to false; otherwise, returns expr2. Thus, when used with Boolean values, && returns true if both operands are true; otherwise, returns false.

`return` is not an expression, so it can't be used as `expr1` or `expr2`.

Since it is going to "return expr2" if expr1 can be converted to false, you are essentially saying `var x = return true`, which obviously (I hope) wouldn't work - (return is a statement, not an expression, so can't be used in this way).

If you want to simplify the code, you could do:

```
function inGUI(x, y){ // check if is in gui
    var is_inside = false;
    for (var i = DEBUG.children.length; !is_inside; i--;){
        var gui = DEBUG.children[i];
        is_inside = isInside.call(gui,x,y);
    };
    return is_inside;
};
```

Comment: thank you , i understand now, nice idea, i will try it, i love it

Comment: I keep your example I love it, i found it clean.

Comment: however I correct, a keyboard error on your side. delete le last ;

Answer (score 2):

`return` is a statement not an expression. The difference is expressions evaluate to a value that can be used in an expression context.

If `return` was an expression the you could use it like that, but you could also do things like `console.log(return 5);` or `var x = return 1;`. It's not clear exactly what those should do since return also stops execution of the remainder of a function. It makes more sense for `return` to be a statement which means it can't be used in places where values are expected, such as an operand to the `&&` operator.