# How to use ternary operator for a return in JS?

Tags: javascript

I have a function to check sums in an array :

```
function checkSum(array, sum) {
   // array = [1,4,6,11]  sum = 10
   var answers = [];
   var map = new Map();

   for (var x = 0; x < array.length; x++) {
       if (map.has(array[x])) {
           answers.push([sum - array[x], array[x]])
       } else {
           map.set(sum - array[x])  
       }
   }


   answers.length != 0 ? console.log(answers) : console.log("nada")
}
```

I originally had the last line just `return answers;` but let's say I don't want to return an empty array -- instead, I'd rather just log a statement.

why doesn't a `return` in a ternary conditional work such as this:

```
answers.length != 0 ? return answers : console.log("nada")
```

Comment: You can put the return in front of the ternary. And it will either return answers of the result of console.log, which is undefined.

Comment: You cannot use a `return` inside a ternary operator: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35231609/why-we-cannot-have-return-in-ternary-operator#35231691

Comment: `return` is a statement, not an expression.

Comment: Don't abuse ternary for if-else...... except in code-golf.

Answer (score 5):

You need to use `return answers.length != 0 ? answers : console.log("nada")`. The reason it fails is because ternary conditions do not support `return` in their conditions. Infact, the ternary operator evaluates to an expression and expressions do not contain a return statement.

```js
function checkSum(array, sum) {
  // array = [1,4,6,11]  sum = 10
  var answers = [];
  var map = new Map();

  for (var x = 0; x < array.length; x++) {
    if (map.has(array[x])) {
      answers.push([sum - array[x], array[x]])
    } else {
      map.set(sum - array[x])
    }
  }


  return answers.length != 0 ? answers : console.log("nada")
}

console.log(checkSum([1, 4, 6, 11], 10));
```

Comment: makes sense, thanks.  `return answers.length != 0 ? answers : console.log("nada")` reads sort of weird, right?  Is a standard `if` statement better practice?

Comment: @JasonBoyas there is nothing such as standard. It depends on the way you code or the way situation demands

Comment: Don't put "nada" inside consol.log. return answers.length != 0 ? answers : "nada"

Comment: @AmitMankotia agree on that. But the answer was given based on OP's code context.

Answer (score 3):

The ternary (conditional) operator expects the "expr1" part (where `return answers` is) to be an *expression* - that is, something that can be evaluated to a value, which can be used in other expressions. But a `return` statement is a *statement*, one which cannot possibly be interpreted as value, or as an expression; hence, a syntax error is thrown.

Instead of

```
answers.length != 0 ? console.log(answers) : console.log("nada")
```

either use a standard if statement:

```
if (answers.length !== 0) return answers;
console.log('nada');
```

or, if you just want to log, put the conditional operator *inside* the `console.log` instead:

```
console.log(
  answers.length === 0
  ? 'nada'
  : answers
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I used ternary operators like this a lot in the past. It's fun, and keeps it to one line.

It can certainly be done, as Ankit shows, by putting the return statement out front

```
return answers.length != 0 ? answers : console.log('nada')
```

But I would recommend you use a classic `if` statement for this. Particularly since you're testing whether to return a value or just log one.

```
if (answers.length != 0) {
    return answers;
};
console.log('nada')
```

I would go even further and recommend that you return the same value type no matter what. This will go a long way for using your function, well - functionally. In this case, that would involve still returning the array (even if it's empty) and logging the `nada` as well if empty.

```
if (answers.length == 0) {
    console.log('nada');
};
return answers;
```