# Question about ternary operator within for loop

Tags: javascript

just having a bit of curiosity about why one bit of code with if /else statement within for loop works and another simplified with a ternary operator, doesn't work.

the instructions are: Define a function takeWhile that takes a callback function and an array as arguments. takeWhile will iterate through the array, passing each array element to the callback as an argument. Every sequential array value that returns true from the callback should be collected in a new array. As soon as an array value returns false from the callback, takeWhile should return this new array.

This code works fine:

```
const takeWhile = (cb, arr) => {
  // ADD CODE HERE...
  //empty array to push true values into 
  const result = [];
  //for loop
  for(let i in arr){
  //if callback yields true, push to result array.
    if(cb(arr[i])){ 
      result.push(arr[i]);
    // else return result
    } else {
      return result;
    }
  }
  //once loop has concluded, return result
  return result;
};

/*
 * Uncomment the following lines and Run Code to test your work
 */
const isEven = (elem) => (elem % 2 === 0);
console.log(takeWhile(isEven, [2,4,5,6,8])); // -> [2,4]
console.log(takeWhile(isEven, [7, 100, 14])); // -> []
console.log(takeWhile(isEven, [10, 8, 6, 4, 2])); // -> [10, 8, 6, 4, 2]
```

this code is using(what I think) is identical logic, but is not filling the result array and returning correctly, using ternary operator.

```
const takeWhile = (cb, arr) => {
  //empty array to push true values into 
  const result = [];
  //for loop
  for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
  //if callback yields true, push to result array, else return result
    return cb(arr[i]) ? result.push(arr[i]) : result;
  } 
  return result;
};

/*
 * Uncomment the following lines and Run Code to test your work
 */
const isEven = (elem) => (elem % 2 === 0);
console.log(takeWhile(isEven, [2,4,5,6,8])); // -> [2,4]
console.log(takeWhile(isEven, [7, 100, 14])); // -> []
console.log(takeWhile(isEven, [10, 8, 6, 4, 2])); // -> [10, 8, 6, 4, 2]
```

for example

```
console.log(takeWhile(isEven, [2,4,5,6,8])); // -> [2,4]
```

returns 1, when it should return [2,4]

Comment: Notice how in the `result.push(arr[i]);` branch, there’s no `return`. You’re returning unconditionally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`return cb(arr[i]) ? result.push(arr[i]) : result;`

That says: if passing the current array item to the callback returns a truthy value, then return the length of the result array after you've pushed the current item to it, otherwise return the result array.

`Array.prototype.push` returns the length of the array. And the ternary here will return on the first loop either way.

Answer (score 1):

Your logic before was to only return if `cb(arr[i])` was falsy. Now you always return after the first loop iteration.

Also `array.push` returns the length of the new array, not the new array. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push

Answer (score 0):

Consider the line of your second example.

```
return cb(arr[i]) ? result.push(arr[i]) : result;
```

This will end the function in the first loop regardless of the conditions. Although function will return according to condition but it will return in the first iteration.

Ternary operators can only be used instead of `if-else` statements if they don't include any statements. `return` is a statement in above code.

This is not asked but just for information you can use `filter()` for simpler code.

```
const getEvens = (arr) => arr.filter(x => x % 2 === 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

This condition:

```
if(cb(arr[i])){ 
   result.push(arr[i]);
   // else return result
} else {
   return result;
}
```

is not the same as:

```
return cb(arr[i]) ? result.push(arr[i]) : result;
```

In the first you return only when `!cb(arr[i])` wich is not possible using ternary operator because the operands of the ternary operator are [expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#Expressions). And `return` is a [statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements). You should use `if else`.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve expected result, modify ternary as below

```
cb(arr[i]) ? result.push(arr[i]) : i = arr.length;
```

1. Remove return with in for loop to execute
2. return of result.push(arr[i]) is the length of values pushed
3. second parameter of ternary change **i** value to length of array to stop for loop

Other issue from ternary and first option from your code , there is no return option available with ternary as below

```
 cb(arr[i]) ? result.push(arr[i]) : return result; // invalid syntax but equivalent to option 1 logic which you are trying
```

Please refer this link - [Why can't we have return in the ternary operator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35231609/why-cant-we-have-return-in-the-ternary-operator)

code sample

```js
const takeWhile = (cb, arr) => {
  //empty array to push true values into 
  const result = [];
  //for loop
  for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
  //if callback yields true, push to result array, else return result
    cb(arr[i]) ? result.push(arr[i]) : i = arr.length;

  } 
  return result;
};

/*
 * Uncomment the following lines and Run Code to test your work
 */
const pushVal = (val) => {
  result.push(arr[i]);
  return result
}
const isEven = (elem) => (elem % 2 === 0);
console.log(takeWhile(isEven, [2,4,5,6,8])); // -> [2,4]
console.log(takeWhile(isEven, [7, 100, 14])); // -> []
console.log(takeWhile(isEven, [10, 8, 6, 4, 2])); // -> [10, 8, 6, 4, 2]
```

codepen - https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/xoGOOQ