# 'If Else' ternary operator inside EventListener not working

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

Came across this situation and can't figure why this works:

```
window.addEventListener( 'scroll', () => {
    const pageHeight = window.pageYOffset
     if ( pageHeight  > 10 ) {
      console.log(pageHeight)
     }
} )
```

And this doesn't:

```
window.addEventListener( 'scroll', () => {
    const pageHeight = window.pageYOffset
    pageHeight > 10 ? console.log(pageHeight)
} )
```

Comment: you forgot the "else" clause (colon). remember, ternary implies three parts. you only put two. also you must have received an error message (if only syntax error) at which point you ought to have gone and looked up the syntax.

Comment: @kindall Thank you. But why the downvote?

Comment: The proper name for his is the *conditional operator*. It's *a type of* ternary operator where "ternary" means "takes three operands". Similar to "binary" which takes two (e.g., multiplication is binary `a * b`) or unary which takes one (e.g., boolean NOT is unary `!a`). You are supplying two of the three operands for an operator that is *defined as one that takes three operands*.

Comment: @VLAZ Thank you very much. :)

Comment: but i tried `return` after the colon, still doesn't work

Comment: [Why can't we have return in the ternary operator?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35231609)

Comment: @VLAZ Thanks again

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because ternary operators require that you define a "else" clause. Look at the documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator

You can do

```js
window.addEventListener( 'scroll', () => {
    const pageHeight = window.pageYOffset
    pageHeight > 10 ? console.log(pageHeight) : null
} )
```

For this case you can also use short-circuiting and do

```js
window.addEventListener( 'scroll', () => {
    const pageHeight = window.pageYOffset
    pageHeight > 10 && console.log(pageHeight)
} )
```

Comment: wonderful. Thank you so much. I was struggling to find remember the JS equivalent to 'return'