# Why some statements can't be used with boolean operators

Tags: javascript

I like to use this style for single line conditional function calls:

```js
debug && console.log('Debug is on');
```

It's much more terse than it's `if` counter part.

However some statements dont work, e.g. `return` and `debugger`:

```js
error && return null
(value == '43') && debugger;
```

Why does it not work for the above statements? Instead I use:

```js
if (error) return null;
if (value == '43') debugger;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the same reason you can't say things like these:

```js
const foo = if (bar) { 5 } else { "hi" };
const baz = try { somethingThatCanFail(); } catch (err) { console.error(err); fallback(); };
```

Javascript, like a lot of other programming languages, retains the difference between an *expression* and a *statement*. You can't use a statement in a place where syntactically an expression is expected.

Expressions evaluate to a value, even if that value is `undefined`. An invocation of a function is an expression. Even an assignment is an expression. But things like `try`, `return`, and `if` are statements.

In some programming languages (notably most functional languages) everything is an expression and evaluates to a value.

Comment: Thanks for the explaination, it makes sense! In python one can do `foo = 5 if bar else "hi";` which is kind of cool, but it doesnt have the ternary operator which is also cool.

Comment: I'd like to add that operators like `&&` expect valid _operands_ (conceptually similar to arguments passed to a function), so one could also say that a "statement" isn't a valid operand. Imagine `&&` being implemented as a function: `and(error, return null)` wouldn't be something one could make sense of.

Comment: @run_the_race Python is an interesting case because while it retains the distinction it tries to make a lot of things that are statements in other languages into expressions. You already mentioned `if`, there's also list comprehensions that turn `for` into an expression.

Answer (score 1):

When you use the boolean operator, it has to be an expression, not a statement.  Some of those keywords/operators are only valid full statements

Here is a related question to explain more
[Why can't we have return in the ternary operator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35231609/why-cant-we-have-return-in-the-ternary-operator)